# Proc summary: outputting median and quartiles

Tags: sas

I am having trouble outputting the measures I have listed before. I was wondering why the quartiles and median are not showing up when I run this statement.

```
proc summary data = full MEAN STD MEDIAN MIN MAX MEDIAN Q1 Q3;
    class type;
    output out=work.summary;
    run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statistics in the `PROC SUMMARY` statement only control what is output to the ODS destinations active (the screen, usually).  If you want them in the dataset, you need to either specify them in the output statement:

```
output out=work.summary mean= std= median= min= max= median= q1= q3= /autoname;
```

Or use ODS OUTPUT to redirect the ODS stream to an output dataset.

```
ods output summary=work.summary;
proc summary data = full MEAN STD MEDIAN MIN MAX MEDIAN Q1 Q3 print;
    class type;
    run; 
ods output clsoe;
```

The `PRINT` keyword is necessary there given the use of `PROC SUMMARY` over `PROC MEANS`.

Comment: Would you know how to add the 90th 95th and 5th percentiles?

Comment: Percentiles are added with P set of keywords: `P95` is 95th percentile, etc.  See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/a000146729.htm#a003281428 for more detail.

Comment: Is there a way to have the variable summaries in different rows as opposed to the same row? Right now it is VAR1...summary..VAR2... I want the summaries for each variable in different rows.

Comment: Yes.  Go ahead and ask that as a separate question - it's something that deserves its own topic, I think.  In short the `stackodsoutput` option is valid in 9.3+ and would do what you want.